# Foreign Key Constraints Hell

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a MySQL InnoDB database with users, products, brands and categories.

There are a lot of foreign keys involved - product added from user, product brand, product category, users following brands...

Every time I try to delete a record, a foreign key constraint fails, I go to delete the other record then,  and another fail because of something else, and they are all tangled up.

This is how I've set them up:

```
ON DELETE restrict
ON UPDATE cascade
```

I dont know why, I just read that  it was good to set it up this way.

I want to be able to delete records flawlessly, how can I do that? And what would be the eventual drawbacks of another method, different than this one?

Comment: What you are facing *is* the flawless way. The way you want, would leave records with no meaning.

Comment: Flawlessly - I try to delete something and it gets deleted. No matter what its relationships with other items are

Comment: well how can I delete records for debugging purposes at least. there is a record that is in the way

Comment: If you make deletion easy (i.e. using `ON DELETE CASCADE`), it would also make it easy to remove many rows using those keys without any trace. Pick your priorities - what is more important to you.

Comment: @J.Kowalski Use `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've used -

```
ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

the DBMS would not let you delete any of the related records while the others exist. To delete all the related records in all the child table when you delete a parent record, use

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

or

```
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

if you want the foreign key field set to `NULL`

From the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) -

> - CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table.
>     Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported. Between
>     two tables, do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act
>     on the same column in the parent table or in the child table. Note:
>     Currently, cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers.
> - RESTRICT: Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table. Specifying RESTRICT (or NO ACTION) is the same as omitting the
>     ON DELETE or ON UPDATE clause.
> - SET NULL: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and set the foreign key column or columns in the child table to NULL. Both ON DELETE SET NULL and ON UPDATE SET NULL clauses are supported.

Comment: if I have a MESSAGES table and I delete a MESSAGE, and the setting is on delete cascade, will the message deletion delete the user as well?

Comment: I don't know how Message and User is related, so can't say exactly.

Comment: User has sent messages to other users. This message has sender_id  that is a foreign key pointing to the user_id

Comment: In this case, Message table is the child table. So, No, delete message wont delete the User record. But deleting the User record would delete all the messages that user is related to.

Comment: I want to delete the user but I want the messages to stay and maybe  sender_id to become null is that possible?

Comment: tried to set it to SET NULL, but I got the following error: Error creating foreign key on brand_first_added_from (check data types)

Comment: Please search for the answers. These are pretty basic problems. Millions others have faced them before.

Answer (score -1):

Just don't use foreign key constaints. Problem solved.

It's much easier to managed this kind of stuff yourself in whatever programming language you prefer, instead of trying to get MySQL to do it for you.

Also you can temporarily shut down foreign key constraints with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINTS=0;`. That's what Sequel Pro and phpMyAdmin and so on do.